# Enumerate C++ imported functions from other libs

Tags: c++, macos, frameworks, linker

I am working on Mac OS X 10.7 with Xcode 4.2. I have the source code of the complex program `Foo` written in C++ using a lot of frameworks. It also use the `Bar.framework`. How could I view the list of the functions program `Foo` uses from `Bar.framework`? I think this information is available at link time, so how could I retrieve it?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that comes to mind is using `nm` tool.

You need a list of all object files of `Foo` library:

```
nm --demangle --undefined-only <foo_obj_files> | grep "Bar.framework"
```

This won't display inline functions from `Bar.framework` though.

Comment: then again, the inlined functions aren't _imported_ as such